Does a VO2 max test have a mental discipline component?
I've often wondered about the "Max" portion of a VO2Max test?
Is there a component of the test that is dependent not on how far you can push your body, but on how far you are willing to push your body?
For comparison, the instruction "how your breath for as long as you can" might seem very simple, and a test of your lung capacity ... except if I choose to do so, I can hold my breath up to a much more aggressive limit than I think most people contemplate. I can hold my breath 10-20 seconds beyond the point of "my sub-conscious nervous system is has capitulated and is desperately trying to breathe": my chest and diaphragm are physically heaving to breathe (clearly visible to others), I can feel panic chemicals affecting me, and the only reason I'm not breathing is that I still have conscious control of my lips and throat and am sealing them shut. When my mind finally capitulates, I gasp explosively and am "gasping for life" for 10+ seconds, and it takes me over a minute to recover. When doing casual "hold your breath tests" ... no-one else ever seems to do this. (Though I imagine there are actual competitions, and that the competitors do)
This isn't a reflection of my lung capacity or my body's consumption of O2 ... it's a reflection of my mental stubborn-ness (or stupidity, take your pick) in overriding my body's physical demands.
In the same way, does a VO2Max test measure/depend upon how far you can push yourself, or how far you will push yourself?
To put it another way:

Does the test depend on/look at "How long you can hold yourself at some limit?"/"What ever-increasing value you give up at"?
Or do you just need to push yourself "very hard" to the point at which you've hit an internal consumption limit, and hold yourself there for "a while" in order to get a stable reading.


TL;DR
A well-done lab test shows when you are not going all out. Will-power is more about where the power goes (and how much of your max power output of your individual muscles you are able to use), while this variable determines your systemic max power output.
Long answer
VO2Max is, essentially, the maximum amount of oxygen (in litres) your body can absorb via the lungs (per minute, per kg body weight), which depends on how much can be transported through your body and how much is consumed due to the relative gas pressure necessary for oxygen to get from the air into the blood in the first place (source).
As such, it is an objective measure that almost exclusively is determined by how much blood volume your heart can transport per stroke and the concentration of haemoglobin in your blood, as I explain in this answer of mine over on MedicalSciences.SE.
You cannot really not go all out in these lab tests since your heart rate is monitored and the max heart rate is pretty consistent over populations given the same age. Outliers are identified in baseline measurements. Additionally, since CO2 going out and O2 going in are measured, they take your so-called respiratory exchange ratio, which, when going above 1.0 (CO2 out vs. O2 in), shows that your body taps into acid buffer systems because there is not enough O2 to fully metabolise energy sources and lactate is building up. Therefore, if you stay significantly below what you are able to do, they'll notice. Going significantly above that by sheer will power is impossible as well since the heart becomes arythmic above a certain rate, which then again evens out over the course of a minute, and too much acid slows down metabolic processes needed to produce the energy for your muscles.
Also, they just ask you (with the help of a Borg scale) how much effort you put in. You may cheat that but your measurements will still tell the truth.
Now, where does your "mental discipline" come into play? Basically, every time you do not measure in a laboratory (where actual O2 consumption is measured over a mask), but use any approximation by exercise output instead. Of course, the tests all say "as fast as you can" but that is very much relative to several factors that do not depend on the real VO2Max at all, e.g. breathing technique: When you have a bad technique in breathing, a significant amount of your VO2Max is consumed by the muscles that do the breathing itself, leaving less to be used for actual exercise output.
The same can be said about overcoming muscle and mental fatigue: With the ability to keep your focus and push further, you may reach better test outcomes in terms of athletic feats although your maximum systemic consumption may be lower.

Ah, no I was talking about it being done in a lab, with a mask. :D

I think the question was whether you may get a low measurement in the lab test if you don't push yourself hard enough (or for long enough) on the treadmill in the lab to really maximise your oxygen consumption.  I suspect that wouldn't be a problem for elite athletes, but it might be for recreational runners (I've seen at least one YouTube video that made that suggestion)?

@Brondahl Added a paragraph in the middle to address that specifically. Does this help to answer your question?

Yeah, that feels like it's expressing the answer now (which I believe can be summarised as: if the test is administered professionally, you could get an invalid result, but realistically the person administerring would notice and be able to tell you that you should be going further. And that pushing "extra hard", mentally, is a thing which happens at a different sort of grain/axis to the stuff being measured in a VO2Max test.

If you think that you could fairly summarise your own answer in <20 words, personally I'd add a TLDR to the top of the answer, but I'm aware that there is a good proportion of SE that doesn't share my taste in that :D

@Brondahl Good idea, done

"You cannot really not go all out in these lab tests since your heart rate is monitored and the max heart rate is pretty consistent over populations given the same age and sex." This is flat out wrong and makes me question the rest of your comment. https://www.jacc.org/doi/full/10.1016/S0735-1097%2800%2901054-8 is one study that discusses the accuracy of such equations and checkout the chart, there is one 20-something with the same maximum heart rate as a 60-something. Ergo, going simply by a "max heart rate via age and sex" equation would say that 20 something didn't try hard enough!

@joeyfb 1) There are always outliers and medical conditions should be precluded. 2) You are correct, the assertion is for people who have an active lifestyle. Yes, general assertions have exceptions. And yes, I won't write here about the whole procedure with baseline measurement etc that accounts exactly for these (rare) cases.

@PhilipKlöcking if you are looking at the same chart I saw you will see while there is a clear trend very few people fall perfectly on that best fit line. I called out an outlier pair but in general doing a formula based on age will is really just an OK guess. I think that really points to some validity in the  "if you don't try hard enough you VO2max could be wrong.

@joeyfb There is a baseline test and you have a lot more than just the heart rate while doing this. For example, extra systolic phases will show. I know you try to prove a point there and yeah, you can validly nitpick that my formulation isn't 100% accurate (even though it is referenced in one of the papers cited in me MedSciences post, just so you know). Yet, the paper you cite clearly states in its own conclusions that there is a .9 correlation with age regardless of sex with 80% of the variance explained by age alone, SD about 10 beats/min. That is statistically saying "it's age alone".

@joeyfb Also, your paper names two more indicators used to assert volitional effort as standard procedure in lab tests: "The maximal respiratory exchange ratio (1.17 ± 0.06) and maximal rating of perceived exertion (19.1 ± 0.8) were not different across ages, suggesting consistently similar voluntary maximal efforts." In other words: They look whether you tap into your acid buffer system because O2 isn't enough anymore (metabolic CO2 to O2 ratio above 1) and ask you how exhausted you feel.
